# Output confusion

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

Shouldn't the output be: Heo Word? as it will print the letter as long as they aren't 'l', but the output I get is: eo World?

```
   #include <iostream> 
   using namespace std; 
   int main() {  
       char str[] = "Hello World\n";  
       char* p = str;   
       while ( *p++ ) {
           if ( *p != 'l' )       
               cout << *p;
       } 
   }
```

Comment: In wrong place pointer is increased. `p++` should be done at the end of while loop, not in the condition.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26cf356fec3ea7a2

Comment: Or use a `for` loop with `++p` as last statement in the for loop header: `for( ;*p;++p)    
              {
                  if ( *p != 'l' )       
                  cout << *p;

              } `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the `while` loop condition already increments the pointer value

```
while ( *p++ )
```

thus the check inside the loops scope

```
if ( *p != 'l' )
```

always misses the 1st character.

The easiest and most comprehensible way to rewrite this loop is probably

```
 char str[] = "Hello World\n";  
 for (char*p = str; *p; ++p) {
     if ( *p != 'l' )       
         cout << *p;
 }
```

Working [online example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f577a5a8eebc0bdb).